# What is best way to define a style for a Accordion?

Tags: 2sxc

We are using a Accordion on the site https://wettkampf-software-zimmer.de/products/lsm. We want to change the color blue. What is best way to define a style for a Accordion? We don't find a tutorial. We are using Oqtane Framework 4.0.3 and 2sxc App 16.02.00.

We are looking on the page "customize & design" https://2sxc.org/en/learn/getting-started-creating-stuff-overview. We don't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Accordion V4. You can edit the template of the app that is installed.

Open the app in a local editor (VSCode is recommended for 2sxc development). The app should be located at `<DNN Root>/Portals/<Your Site>/2sxc/Accordion4/`.

Depending on whether you are using bootstrap 3, 4, or 5, you'll edit the appropriate stylesheet inside `bs3/`, `bs4/`, or `bs5/`. In this case, the blue color set by the `$secondary` variable, which can be set in `bsX/styles/_variables.scss`.

`.scss` files are Sass, not raw CSS, so you'll have to build the project. This can be done with `npm`, part of `NodeJS`, by running `npm ci` followed by `npm run build-bsX`.

In my case, this app had some conflicts in it's `package-lock.json`, so I deleted `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules/` folder (if present) and ran `npm install` to get the latest versions of the modules.